# gacutil - cannot launch on vista x64

Tags: windows, gac, windows-vista, gacutil

I thought this was a privilege issue but I logged on as admin and still couldn't get more than a brief flash of the command window. I am just double clicking on the exe file I found in the 7.0 sdk

As a side question, can you just go into the GAC manually and delete something??

Cheers,
Berryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a command-line utility. You ran it without arguments (by the sound of it) and it quickly exited. Run cmd.exe and run gacutil from there.

You can also use the Windows Explorer extension to delete assemblies - just browse to C:\Windows\assembly (or whatever your Windows directory is).

Comment: Pretty sure you shouldn't be mucking around with the GAC contents manually.

Comment: The Explorer shell extension isn't hacking it "manually" - that's the normal, supported GUI. You ''can'' hack it manually from the command line and I'd agree that you shouldn't do that unless it's really stuffed.

Comment: I did actually delete the assembly in explorer first, but gacutil still found it. Maybe I missed something when I was in there...